# Raspberry Pi camera recording video lag but CPU usage is low

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, raspberry-pi

I am developing a device with raspberryPi which can record the 6-axis acceleration and angular speed(MPU9250 though i2c), and filming the environment by Picamera at the same time.

But when I saving the 6-axis data to memory and filming the video, my QT4 GUI become very slow and after I stop the recording and check my video, my video is lag and it looks like lost a lot of frames.

I know recording 6-axis data in every 6 millis sec(while True method) is a hard work but I found that the cpu using rate was only 1% in recording and other X-windows functions could open smoothly. That confusing me.

my code url list below and maybe anyone could help?

https://github.com/mikechan0731/RaspBerryPi_MPU9250_data_read/blob/master/IMU_GUI.py

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am silly lol

I found if I add one line "time.sleep(0.0001)" in "while True" function and everything will be ok